# I'm trying to convert simple SoapUI project to Composite Project using SoapUI5.0.0, Does any one know how to do this?

Tags: soapui

i read many links but not getting proper solution.i try to search in property of project but couldn't find composite option.if any one know API please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to have the Pro-Version of SoapUI.
If you have purchased a license you can convert it by the following steps:

- Click on the project to be converted (in the project navigator)
- Now in the lower left corner switch the project property "Composite Project" to true
- Click the "Save all projects" button

That's it, good luck

Comment: I need to do it with SoapUI5.0.0, is there is any solution to do it with out using pro-version?

Comment: I mean using any API.